# Returning an object in java with a double?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, subclass, superclass

I have a very simple solution but I have not yet learned how to do it and cannot figure out how to solve the problem.

I have an Interface class:

```
public interface Analyzable { 
  double getAverage();
  GradedActivity getHighest();
  GradedActivity getLowest();
}
```

This was given to me by my professor. I changed his code from the two GradedActivity to doubles and had no problem returning them in this code. However I am having trouble returning them as GradedActivity's

```
public GradedActivity getHighest() {
    double highest = grades[0].getScore();
    for(int i = )......
    //Code works and returns correct number (tested)
    return highest;
```

this code gives me this error 
"Double cannot be converted to GradedActivity"

this is my GradedActivity code

```
public class GradedActivity { 
private double score;

public GradedActivity() {
}

public void setScore(double s) {
    score = s;
}

public double getScore() {
    return score;
}

public char getGrade() {
    char letterGrade;
    if(score >= 90)
        letterGrade = 'A';
    else if(score >= 80)
        letterGrade = 'B';
    else if(score >= 70)
        letterGrade = 'C';
    else if(score >= 60)
        letterGrade = 'D';
    else
        letterGrade = 'F';

    return letterGrade;
}
```

}

this is the CourseGrades code

```
enter code here
```

public class CourseGrades extends GradedActivity implements Analyzable
{
    private GradedActivity[] grades = new GradedActivity[4];

```
public CourseGrades()
{

}

public void setLab(GradedActivity lab)
{
    grades[0] = lab;
}

public void setPassFailExam(PassFailExam passFailExam)
{
    grades[1] = passFailExam;
}

public void setEssay(GradedActivity essay)
{
    grades[2] = essay;
}

public void setFinalExam(FinalExam finalExam)
{
    grades[3] = finalExam;
}



public String toString() {
    String str;
    str = "Lab Score: " + grades[0].getScore() + 
                        "\t\t\tGrade: " + grades[0].getGrade() +  
                "\nP/F Exam Score: " + grades[1].getScore() +
                        "\t\tGrade: " + grades[1].getGrade() + 
                "\nEssay Score: " + grades[2].getScore() + 
                        "\t\tGrade: " + grades[2].getGrade() + 
                "\nFinal Exam Score: " + grades[3].getScore() + 
                        "\t\tGrade: " + grades[3].getGrade();
    return str;
}

public double getAverage() 
{
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        sum += grades[i].getScore();
    }
    double ave = sum/4;
    return ave;
}

public GradedActivity getHighest() {

    double highest = grades[0].getScore();
    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if(grades[i].getScore() > highest)
            highest = grades[i].getScore();         
    }
    return highest;
}

public GradedActivity getLowest() {
    double lowest = grades[0].getScore();
    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if(grades[i].getScore() < lowest)
            lowest = grades[i].getScore();          
    }
    return setScore(lowest);
}
```

}

this is the interface

public class CourseGrades extends GradedActivity implements Analyzable
{
    private GradedActivity[] grades = new GradedActivity[4];

```
public CourseGrades()
{

}

public void setLab(GradedActivity lab)
{
    grades[0] = lab;
}

public void setPassFailExam(PassFailExam passFailExam)
{
    grades[1] = passFailExam;
}

public void setEssay(GradedActivity essay)
{
    grades[2] = essay;
}

public void setFinalExam(FinalExam finalExam)
{
    grades[3] = finalExam;
}



public String toString() {
    String str;
    str = "Lab Score: " + grades[0].getScore() + 
                        "\t\t\tGrade: " + grades[0].getGrade() +  
                "\nP/F Exam Score: " + grades[1].getScore() +
                        "\t\tGrade: " + grades[1].getGrade() + 
                "\nEssay Score: " + grades[2].getScore() + 
                        "\t\tGrade: " + grades[2].getGrade() + 
                "\nFinal Exam Score: " + grades[3].getScore() + 
                        "\t\tGrade: " + grades[3].getGrade();
    return str;
}

public double getAverage() 
{
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        sum += grades[i].getScore();
    }
    double ave = sum/4;
    return ave;
}

public GradedActivity getHighest() {

    double highest = grades[0].getScore();
    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if(grades[i].getScore() > highest)
            highest = grades[i].getScore();         
    }
    return highest;
}

public GradedActivity getLowest() {
    double lowest = grades[0].getScore();
    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if(grades[i].getScore() < lowest)
            lowest = grades[i].getScore();          
    }
    return setScore(lowest);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

As a double can not be cast to a `GradedActivity` you need to create one first, set the value (I would create a constructor) and then return it.

try

```
   GradedActivity highGA = new GradedActivity();
   highGA.setScore (highest);
   return highGA;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the value and wrap in a `GradedActivity` instance and return it, for example...

```
public GradedActivity getHighest() {
    double highest = grades[0].getScore();
    for(int i = )......
    //Code works and returns correct number (tested)

    GradedActivity ga = new GradedActivity();
    ga.setScore(highest);
    return ga;
```

Answer (score 0):

Java won't convert from `double` to `GradedActivity` automatically you must create an new instance of GradedActivity and set its value.

```
GradedActivity ga = new GradedActivity(); // create instance
ga.setScore(value); // set value
return ga; // return GradedActivity instead of double
```